# Calling javascript function from codebehind error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I am trying to call one of my javascript functions that loaded in my master page from an aspx page.

Below is the code i am currently using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", "showNotifier(3000,'green','test');", True)
```

The javascript code is this:

```
function showNotifier(delayTime, color, theMsg) {
    var theDivName = '#Notifier';
    e.preventDefault();
    $(theDivName).css("background", color);
    $(theDivName).text(theMsg);
    $(theDivName).animate({ top: 0 }, 300, null);
    $(theDivName).css("position", "fixed");

    //Hide the bar
    $notifyTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(theDivName).animate({ top: -100 }, 1500, function () {
            $(theDivName).css("position", "absolute");
        });
    }, delayTime);
});
```

And this is where its being called in my code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", "showNotifier(3000,'green','test');", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

When i run my page and it loads up that aspx page, it displays this error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'showNotifier' is undefined.
```

What would be causing this?

Comment: And where does showNotifier live? Is the code on the page?

Comment: @epascarello: showNotifier is a javascript file thats loaded up inside the master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead.

And also wrap your call in $(function() { ... } ).:

```
;$(function() {showNotifier(3000,'green','test');});
```

**UPDATE**: So your VB code will look like so:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", ";$(function() {showNotifier(3000,'green','test');});", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2** Your js function has some syntax errors:

```
function showNotifier(delayTime, color, theMsg) {
    var theDivName = '#Notifier';
    // 'e' is not declared -- e.preventDefault();
    $(theDivName).css("background", color);
    $(theDivName).text(theMsg);
    $(theDivName).animate({ top: 0 }, 300, null);
    $(theDivName).css("position", "fixed");

    //Hide the bar
    $notifyTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(theDivName).animate({ top: -100 }, 1500, function () {
            $(theDivName).css("position", "absolute");
        });
    }, delayTime);
}// ); - this should not be here
```

Comment: Says that **RegisterClientScript is not a member of System.Web.UI.ScriptManager**

Comment: Sorry, use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Still shows my original error of **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'showNotifier' is undefined.**

Comment: Hmm... can you open the generated HTML and see that the function is defined there? Also, there is a bracket at the end of function - it should be removed.

Comment: Got it that time. It was because of the error in the javascript. Blah wish MS would tell me that instead of giving me that generic error!